# Using pattern matching for Ordered.compare in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following Scala class:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
    extends Ordered[Person] {
  def compare(that: Person): Int = {
    if (this.lastName < that.lastName) -1
    else if (this.lastName > that.lastName) 1
    else if (this.firstName < that.firstName) -1
    else if (this.firstName > that.firstName) 1
    else this.age compare that.age
  }
}
```

to allow sorting by lastName, firstName, and age.

How can I write this using pattern matching? I've come up with the following, but is there a better way?

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
    extends Ordered[Person] {
  def compare(that: Person): Int = {
    that match {
      case Person(_, thatLastName, _) if this.lastName < thatFile => -1
      case Person(_, thatLastName, _) if this.lastName > thatFile => 1

      case Person(thatFirstName, _, _) if this.firstName < thatFirstName => -1
      case Person(thatFirstName, _, _) if this.firstName > thatFirstName => 1

      case Person(_, _, thatAge) => this.age compare thatAge
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Changed to use `Ordering[A]` as per Landei's answer:

```
implicit val personOrdering = new Ordering[Person] {
  def compare(first: Person, second:Person): Int = {
    second match {
      case Person(_, thatLastName, _) if first.lastName < thatLastName => -1
      case Person(_, thatLastName, _) if first.lastName > thatLastName => 1

      case Person(thatFirstName, _, _) if first.firstName < thatFirstName => -1
      case Person(thatFirstName, _, _) if first.firstName > thatFirstName => 1

      case Person(_, _, thatAge) => first.age compare thatAge
    }
  }
}

case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
```

but it seems awkward that I only match `second`. How can I make it more "elegant"?

Comment: To me, the better way is clearly without pattern matching in this case…

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet: But what happens when you need to sort by more columns? I think (was hoping) that the pattern-matching version would be more readable, maybe with a little use of whitespace (see update).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The preferred way in Scala is to provide an implicit Ordering instead of Ordered, which is much more flexible and doesn't give a headache concerning inheritance.

Concerning the pattern matching I see no better way, because the result of the compare methods are `Int`s, which are not guaranteed to be -1, 0, 1. Haskell's solution to give back "enum" objects (LT, EQ, GT) is much cleaner and pattern matchable, but it seems Scala followed the C++/Java tradition here for compatibility reasons.

Of course you could roll out your own comparision "framework":

```
abstract sealed class CompResult(val toInt:Int) {
  def andThen(next: => CompResult): CompResult
}
case object LT extends CompResult(-1) {
 def andThen(next: => CompResult) = LT
}
case object EQ extends CompResult(0) {
  def andThen(next: => CompResult) = next
}
case object GT extends CompResult(1) {
  def andThen(next: => CompResult) = GT
}

implicit def int2Comp(n:Int) =
   if (n == 0) EQ else if (n < 0) LT else GT


(("sdkfhs" compareTo "fldgkjdfl"):CompResult) match {
  case LT => println("less")
  case EQ => println("same")
  case GT => println("more")
}
```

In your case you could write:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
  extends Ordered[Person] {
  def compare(that: Person): Int = {
    (this.lastName compareTo that.lastName).
    andThen (this.firstName compareTo that.firstName).
    andThen (this.age compare that.age).toInt
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! A DSL for comparing. But it seems a little "heavy" to compare to `Person` objects :-).

Comment: Given that Scala does not support `Int` enums, having objects instead of integers would have performance consequence. For instance, -1, 0 and 1 _are_ pattern matchable, and they may translate into a switch, whereas `LT`, `EQ` and `GT` will not.

Comment: @Daniel: As always there is a trade-off between readability and performance, but at least you *have* a choice (e.g. in contrast to Java). Of course I wouldn't recommend my solution for any performance-critical code. BTW, for more serious purposes we could "cheat" and use Java enums for LT,EQ and GT (but IMO that would be really "too heavy").

Comment: But using Java enums would loose the nice `andThen` method, which is the coolest thing about your solution. By the way, Scalaz does have something like this... I wonder if they have an `andThen` as well?