# Scala Ordered by multiple fields

Tags: scala

This question is probably quite dumb, but I can't find an example and can't figure it out.

I want to compare two `Person` classes by last, first, and middle name, in that order. Here's the brain-dead way to do it:

```
def compare(that: Person): Int = {
  val last: Int = lastName.compare(that.lastName)
  if (last != 0) last
  else {
    val first: Int = firstName.compare(that.firstName)
    if (first != 0) first
    else middleName.compare(that.middleName)
}
```

I know there's some much more clever way to do this (probably using `Ordering`) but I can't put my finger on it.

Todd

I figured out this once I realized how to access the right things in Ordering.

```
def compare(that: Person): Int = {
  Ordering.Tuple3(Ordering.String, Ordering.String, Ordering.String).compare(
     (lastName, firstName, middleName),
     (that.lastName, that.firstName, that.middleName))
}
```

I'm pretty sure I can get away with fewer explicits, but this works and is reasonably compact.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using pattern matching for Ordered.compare in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715568/using-pattern-matching-for-ordered-compare-in-scala)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Option 1: sortBy

Using the `sortBy` method, this can be pretty simple:

```
case class Person(first: String, middle: String, last: String)
val personList = List(Person("john", "a", "smith"), Person("steve", "x", "scott"), Person("bill", "w", "smith"))
personList.sortBy{ case Person(f,m,l) => (l,f,m) }
```

### Option 2: Extend Ordered[Person]

By extending `Ordered[Person]`, the class will know how to sort itself, so we get things like `sorted`, `min`, and `max` for free:

```
case class Person(first: String, middle: String, last: String) extends Ordered[Person] {
  def compare(that: Person): Int =
    (last compare that.last) match {
      case 0 => 
        (first compare that.first) match {
          case 0 => middle compare that.middle
          case c => c
        }
      case c => c
    }
}

val personList = List(Person("john", "a", "smith"), Person("steve", "x", "scott"), Person("bill", "w", "smith"))
personList.sorted
personList.min
personList.max
```

### Option 3: Implicit Ordering

If you use an implicit `Ordering`, then you get `sorted`, `min`, etc without having that particular ordering tied to your original class.  This decoupling might be convenient, or it might by annoying, depending on your specific case.

```
case class Person(first: String, middle: String, last: String)

implicit val ord = new Ordering[Person] { 
  def compare(self: Person, that: Person): Int =
    (self.last compare that.last) match {
      case 0 => 
        (self.first compare that.first) match {
          case 0 => self.middle compare that.middle
          case c => c
        }
      case c => c
    }
}

val personList = List(Person("john", "a", "smith"), Person("steve", "x", "scott"), Person("bill", "w", "smith"))
personList.sorted
personList.min
personList.max
```

Comment: Once I figured out `StringOrdering` was a trait and not an object, I figured out how to do it. See above.

Comment: this: personList.sortBy{ case Person(f,m,l) => (l,f,m) }  looks a bit like a magic.

Comment: What if you want to invert order for one of the fields, which is String, using trick with tuples? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using scala 2.13+ you can use `Ordering.by` and `orElseBy`. It is quite explicit.

```scala
case class Person(first: String, middle: String, last: String)

implicit val ordering: Ordering[Person] = Ordering.by[Person, String](_.first)
   .orElseBy(_.middle)
   .orElseBy(_.last)

val list = List(Person("john", "a", "smith"), Person("steve", "x", "scott"), Person("bill", "w", "smith"))

list.sorted
```

Comment: This is quite nice, but only available with 2.13 on.

Comment: What to do if second provided ordering should be reversed?